# display spark dataframe in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark

Recently I started to work in Spark using Visual Studio Code and I struggle with displaying my dataframes. When I used to work in databricks, there is `df.display()` which is really good, in jupyter notebooks I can use `.toPandas().head()`, however in VCS, despite importing `pandas`I cannot get this beautiful view in tabular format. Is there any way, because if df consists more than few columns, `.show()` breaks and is unreadable

Answer (score 1):

You cant use print to display the spark dataframe, to display contents of spark dataframe, use the below command

```
use df.show(truncate=False)
```

this will give you spark dataframe in more readable format

Comment: Thats what I though, its pretty bad to show for client during business hours, a print of markdown table, pandas' `head()` or databricks' `.display()` is way more elegant and nice to view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset to display is not too large, I would transform it to pandas and visualise it that way.

```
df.toPandas() # convert to pandas df
```

Complete example (local development):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("app") \
    .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("James", "", "Smith", "36636", "M", 3000),
    ("Michael", "Rose", "", "40288", "M", 4000),
    ("Robert", "", "Williams", "42114", "", 4000),
    ("Maria", "Anne", "Jones", "39192", "F", 4000),
    ("Jen", "Mary", "Brown", "", "F", -1),
]

# write the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("first_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("middle_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("last_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ssn", StringType(), True),
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
])

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# Show DataFrame
df.toPandas()
```